# How to Create listener Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler for every mail folder?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

I can listen on default folder like this:

```
_outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
_inbox = _outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
_items = _inbox.Items;
_items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
```

How can I add a listener on all folders and sub folders ?

Or listen for all incoming mail before it is placed in a folder or subfolder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store Items objects in a list (not just the _items variable) and set up the ItemAdd event handler on all folders that you are interested in.

Comment: Specifically I do not know how to get each folder's `.items` object.

Comment: You need to open the parent MAPIFolder object first. Where do these folders live?

Comment: My mom's house, in the basement with me.