# Is there any Event in Outlook addin when new email arrived in Office365

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there any Event in Outlook addin when new email arrived in Office365.

We have to scan new in coming E-mails and flag them if E-mail contain any suspicious link.
I can scan email on command button click. But I want to make it auto scan when ever user got a new email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature: New e-mail event for Outlook add-ins, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins.

Comment: Do you know if this feature has been implemented or not yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I followed. There are several ways to listen for a new email. For example here is [new email per folder listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147173/how-to-create-listener-outlook-itemsevents-itemaddeventhandler-for-every-mail-fo).