# Event In Outlook Addin (Office JS) whenever an new email arrived

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In using Office JS to sync Outlook email to a third-party system.
I'm trying to flag an email to be marked for automated integration whenever a new reply is received. The reason behind that is we don't want the user to sync the same email every time a new thread/email is received.

I checked this Stack Overflow answer: [Is there any Event in Outlook addin when new email arrived in Office365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271682/is-there-any-event-in-outlook-addin-when-new-email-arrived-in-office365?rq=1)
and it says that this feature is not supported, but this was 3 years ago.

Does anyone know how we can achieve that in Outlook Addin?

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Please read my question before you vote down on my question. The link you provided I mentioned it in my question but as I said it was 3 years ago. And am asking if they implemented recently

Comment: This is a blatant duplicate. Read the SO policies.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has been changed so far. There is no event for handling new emails in web add-ins.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .